# Octave: Center multiline plot label

Tags: plot, label, octave

I would like to have a multiline plot label with the text centered.

The code

```
figure(1)
axis=xlabel(["This is a long first line";"short line"]);
```

Produces the following image

[image]

Changing the horizontal alignment with `set(axis,'HorizontalAlignment','center')` is also not producing the wanted result.

So what do I have to do to have the text of a multiline label centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `["This is a long first line";"short line"]`, you get a left aligned `char` array of size `2 x 25`, which is then fed to `xlabel`. If you instead provide a cell array of strings, you actually provide two separate strings:

```matlab
figure(1)
axis = xlabel({"This is a long first line"; "short line"; "xs"});
```

Looking at the figure, I guess this should be your desired output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just adding that there's no reason for the cell array to be vertical btw (i.e. no need for semicolons here, commas are fine). Unlike the normal array, it's not the "verticalness" of the cell array that causes things to go one below the other in this case. It's just that each element of the cell array will be interpreted as a new line in the label.